# How do I specify this `WHERE` condition without using SQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using the following raw Postgres SQL in my `where()` call to find records where `some_date` is two days from now:

```
SomeModel.where('date(some_date) - date(NOW()) = 2')
```

Can it be written using pure ActiveRecord syntax without raw SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, haven't tested it though.

```
SomeModel.where('date(some_date) = ?', 2.days.ago.to_date)
#or
SomeModel.where('some_date::date = ?', 2.days.ago.to_date)
```

If you want it to be any purer, without the `date` sql function, I'm not seeing it, at least not without creating a db view.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work with the version of where() that takes a hash. :(

Comment: It would be nice but I can live without it. Unless you know an easy way...